# iOS UICollectionView ConsoleLog Caution when Item Width is bigger than CollectionView width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionView for my project and I put bigger Item than collectionView width to hide selectionButton/DeleteButton and show them when Edit mode or Swiped

Everything is working good but there's caution message in ConsoleLog EveryTime

As I know, there're some Messages I can ignore But I want to know if it's Okay to ignore it

Is it okay to put bigger width for item than collectionView width and ignore that Message?

I don't want you to waste your time with reading every Single line of my code and fix for me

So, I just hope to hear your Idea and if there're some points I should be careful when I using this Way :)

```
2020-11-01 19:08:14.917103+0900 IssueTracker[27304:7532603] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-11-01 19:08:14.917210+0900 IssueTracker[27304:7532603] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-11-01 19:08:14.917241+0900 IssueTracker[27304:7532603] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-11-01 19:08:14.917601+0900 IssueTracker[27304:7532603] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10571ae80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x10a811800;
frame = (0 172; 414 515); clipsToBounds = YES;
autoresize = RM+BM;
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2829d5290>;
layer = <CALayer: 0x282780ea0>;
contentOffset: {0, 0};
contentSize: {414, 101};
adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0};
layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x10571ae80>;
dataSource: <IssueTracker.IssueListCollectionViewAdapter: 0x28279a2c0>>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to implement it is by disabling buttons and animating their appearance by changing alpha of text colors. I implemented it this way in my video application and it works perfectly!